# Vue.js 2 - jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js and trying to use a jQuery Gritter plugin to show a notification alert on success after AJAX call.

But, it is not defined, here is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/Vue';
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        body: '',
        team_id: $('#team_id').val()
    },

    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            let self = this;
            axios.post('/tasks', this.$data)
                .then(function (res) {
                    self.$nextTick(function() {
                        self.initGritter(res.data);
                    }.bind(this));
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

        },

        initGritter(data) {
            console.log($); // object
            console.log(jQuery); // object
            console.log($.gritter); //undefined

        }
    },
});
```

If you look at the initGritter method, you will see that jQuery is loaded and ready, but the gritter plugin not.

If I try it in the console, jQuery Gritter is ready on page load... it just does not work through Vue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this.. it worked.

```
initGritter: function(){
     $(function() {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'title',
            text: 'text',
            class_name: 'color warning'
        });
     });
}
```